# Multiple parallel navigable ui next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes

Is it possible to have multiple navigable ui experiences on the same page using next js?

By that I mean being able to navigate such views independently of each other (separate routing).

As far as I know, parallel routes do not allow for such functionality, however, maybe there is another way of achieving this goal?